# SPARQL: get object only if predicate exists

Tags: sparql

I want to get the sources of a `dbo:Cheese`. Some `dbo:Cheese` have `dbo:Animal` as `dbp:source`. Some others have only text. I would like to get the source information in the `?sources` variable regardless of that the source is `dbo:Animal` or text . How should I do it ?

```
SELECT ?cheese
CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?source; SEPARATOR=", "), ", ", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?source_label; SEPARATOR=", ")) AS ?sources
WHERE {
    ?cheese a dbo:Cheese .
    optional { # some cheeses don't have a source informed
        ?cheese dbp:source ?source .
    }
    optional { # some sources are dbo:Animal, some others are xsd:string
        ?source a dbo:Animal ;
                rdfs:label ?source_label .
        FILTER(langMatches(lang(?source_label), "EN"))
    }
}
LIMIT 10
```

I tried this. Problem is that I have both `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sheep` and `Sheep` in `?sources`.

Comment: `SELECT ?cheese
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?s; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?sources
WHERE {
    ?cheese a dbo:Cheese .
    optional { # some cheeses don't have a source informed
        ?cheese dbp:source ?source .
optional { # some sources are dbo:Animal, some others are xsd:string
        ?source a dbo:Animal ;
                rdfs:label ?source_label .
        FILTER(langMatches(lang(?source_label), "EN"))
    }
   BIND(COALESCE(?source_label, ?source) AS ?s)
    }
    
}
LIMIT 10`

Comment: not that I understand why you want the label only if the source as from an animal? Is there a reason for this? IF not, do this: `SELECT ?cheese
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?s; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?sources
WHERE {
    ?cheese a dbo:Cheese .
    optional { # some cheeses don't have a source informed
        ?cheese dbp:source ?source .
optional { # some sources are dbo:Animal, some others are xsd:string
        ?source 
                rdfs:label ?source_label .
        FILTER(langMatches(lang(?source_label), "EN"))
    }
   BIND(COALESCE(?source_label, ?source) AS ?s)
    }
}
LIMIT 100`

Comment: Because if the source is not a `dbo:Animal` it does not have label, does it ?

Comment: OK , so if I understand well some sources are not from animals

Comment: `animal` is an unnecessary restriction, it sufficient to just get the label if such a label exists which is true for all resource (URIs) DBpedia, otherwise if it is only a string literal, just use this as literals can't be subjects of RDF triples, thus, can't have labels